# Space Complexity (Python)

Tags: python, time-complexity, space-complexity

I have a question, supposedly gdc(i, n) time and space complexity is O(1), what is the space complexity for this function?
Time Complexity is O(n) because of a for loop.
How about Space Complexity? The answer is O(1) but I don't understand why... result in a for loop is taking n space so shouldn't it be O(n)?

```
def gcd_fun(n):
   for i in range(1, n+1):
      result += gcd(i, n)
   return result﻿
```

Comment: "result in a for loop is taking n space so shouldn't it be O(n)?" No it isn't. `result` is, presumably, an `int` which (for these purposes) takes a constant amount of space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your python version. If you are using python 2, it creates the list for range function. Respectively, list needs O(n) memory complexity. Otherwise, if you are using python 3, it creates the generator.

UPDATE: As Vineeth said range is not an iterator. Sorry for misleading.

According to documentation:

> The advantage of the range type over a regular list or tuple is that a range object will always take the same (small) amount of memory, no matter the size of the range it represents (as it only stores the start, stop and step values, calculating individual items and subranges as needed).

Comment: `range` isn't a generator it's a `range` object, You can't call `next` on it.

Comment: `range` in Python 3 gives a lazily evaluated sequence, not a generator.

Comment: I am using python 3. So is it still O(n)? The reason is due to list? I am still quite unsure, sorry about that, still really new to complexity in general.